# How to check if List<E> meets requirements of another List<E>

Tags: java

Is there a way that I can check if one list meets the requirements of another? I have a list source and a list destination. The types aren't known yet, which is why they're generic. I'm trying to find a way where it could check if the elements in source would match the type of destination. If so, then the element would be added to destination.

```
public interface UnaryPredicate<E> {

public List<E> copyIf( List<E> source,List<E> destination);

}
```

.

```
public class Copy<E> implements UnaryPredicate{



public List copyIf( List source, List destination)
{                                   


    for (List temp: source)
    {
        //if source meets requirement,
            destination.add(temp);
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args)
{

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible approach, using [Class#isAssignableFrom(Class)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) -

```
public static <E, F> List<F> copyIf(List<E> source,
    List<F> destination, Class<F> cls) {
  for (E e : source) {
    if (cls.isAssignableFrom(e.getClass())) {
      destination.add((F) e);
    }
  }
  return destination;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s = "Hello";
  List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
  al.add(s);
  System.out.println(copyIf(al, new ArrayList<String>(), String.class));
}
```

Output is

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear exactly what you want here. Do you want this done on a per-element basis, or are you simply comparing the types of lists? Could it be done at compile-time instead using slightly more complex generics? What is the purpose of this? Specifically, what are you *trying* to do?

First of all, as you've written your code, you're passing in two separate lists of type `E`. Since they have the same type, they will be verified at compile time, and they will be compatible. However, you might have intended them to be different types, and in that case, things get a little more complicated.

If you're checking on a per-element basis, or if the check must be performed dynamically at runtime, you can't do this without some additional work due to Java's type erasure. You could pass in a class that elements must be compatible with, like this:

```
public List<E> copyIf(Class<E> compatible, List<?> source, List<?> destination);
```

Then you could compare on an element-by-element basis.

On the other hand, if you just need to assure the lists are compatible, just make the compiler do the work:

```
public List<E> copyIf(List<? extends E> source, List<E> destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to guarantee this in compile time by define your generic interface as the parent of all elements, say it's called **IBaseElement**; then

```
List<E extends IBaseElement>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done has already *guaranteed* both source and destination list in compile time.  If you want to pass any kind of source list and do the copy if the object is of type allowed by destination, you need to pass an extra parameter as Class for this purpose, as Generics in Java is based on Erasure, and you cannot do any checking on the type parameter during runtime.

in brief:

```
public List<E> copyIf( List<?> source, List<E> destination, Class<E> destinationType) {
    for (Object o : source) {
        if (destinationType.isInstance(o) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

So it can be used as :

```
copyIf(anyList, destList, DestinationType.class);
```

And, you should allow a more flexible destination so your code can work for more reasonable scenario:

```
public List<E> copyIf( List<?> source, 
                       List<? super E> destination, 
                       Class<E> destinationType) { ....
```